# Why does error like net::ERR_ABORTED 404 occur on an Shopify product details page

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, shopify, front-end-optimization

The error `jerdon-8x1x-reversible-plug-in-make-up-mirror-3-finishes:60 GET https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0048/2675/9279/t/8/assets/mm-init.js?882142460823279530&shop=www-reflectperfection-com.myshopify.com net::ERR_ABORTED 404` is found in the console when visiting the page of our Shopify site.

The URL to the page is:

https://reflectperfection.com/collections/plug-in-wall-mounted-makeup-mirrors/products/jerdon-8x1x-reversible-plug-in-make-up-mirror-3-finishes

Could you please help me understand why this happens and find a solution to it?

Comment: 404 means the resource is not found

Comment: Okay, but what resource is it talking about?. As you can see, the page is rendered with everything need by the visitor.

Comment: I can't see anything, because I don't follow rando links blindly like my grandma would - anyway the resource that isn't found is ... wait for it, how do I know if I didn't go ... it's `https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0048/2675/9279/t/8/assets/mm-init.js` ... because you told us that was it

Comment: I understand what you say about following random links and it is worth keeping that in mind, thanks. Is the 404 error from the resource fixable on our Shopify store?

Comment: don't know, what's trying to load `https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0048/2675/9279/t/8/assets/mm-init.js`?